# Is there a broad map, guide or list of all or most of math's fields?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, learning

Has someone ever garthered all the different fields in maths (single variable function analisis, multivariable analisis, complex number analisis, number theory, graphs, succesions, etc) and made a (vague at least) map of what is needed to know what or at least what are the names of all the different things and concepts that are known to mathmaticians?

I would like to know at least the names of the stuff that i am still ignorant about so that i can look up a book or something about it and read it up.

Comment: http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html

Comment: Web resources that are fairly comprehensive, such as Springer's [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Main_Page), tend to be difficult to "browser" just for high level "names of the stuff" information.  So there's the chicken-and-egg problem of needing to know what things are called before you can ask the question.